# Images somehow linked on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 characters in my game, but the problem is that they are somehow linked on the x-axis. When one moves horizontally, the other does as well. The characters are images, and they move by changing the margin elements. I want them to move separately from each other so that the game will function properly.

I have tried changing the positioning element, and when I change the positioning element to fixed, the problem is gone, but then I can no longer move the images up or down. I have checked all of the code, and no variables overlap between the 2 or anything like that.

**Code:**

```
let img1 = document.querySelector(`.img1`)
let img2 = document.querySelector(`.img2`)
let score1 = 40
let score2 = 40
document.addEventListener(`keydown`, function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
    score1 += 0.5
    img1.style.marginLeft = `${score1}%`
  }
  if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    score1 -= 0.5
    img1.style.marginLeft = `${score1}%`
  }
  if (e.key === 'd') {
    score2 += 0.5
    img2.style.marginLeft = `${score2}%`
  }
  if (e.key === 'a') {
    score2 -= 0.5
    img2.style.marginLeft = `${score2}%`
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `position: absolute` instead. Do not use `margin`, instead use `top` or `left` to move them.

Please also rename your variables, score1 and score2 should be player1x and player2x. Img1 and img2 should be player1Image and player2Image.

Also make sure to add semicolons to the end of each of your lines of code.

Like this:

```
let player1Img = document.querySelector('.img1');
let player2Img = document.querySelector('.img2');
let player1X = 40;
let player2X = 40;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.key == 'ArrowRight'){
      player1X += 0.5;
    }

    if(e.key == 'ArrowLeft'){
      player1X -= 0.5;
    }

    if(e.key == 'd'){
      player2X += 0.5;
    }

    if(e.key == 'a'){
      player2X -= 0.5;
    }

    player1Img.style.left = `${player1X}%`;
    player2Img.style.left = `${player2X}%`;

});
```

Comment: When I use absolute, the images are locked in place/unable to move. Edit: I correctly applied your solution, and it worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problems! Happy to help!! Could you please mark it as the answer since it worked?